# Are there any tags In Struts2 that emulate the 'nested' tag of Struts 1?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

Basically I want to emulate this tag (and behaviour) from Struts 1 in Struts 2:
    Example...

```
<nested:write property="myNestedLevel.propertyOne" />
<nested:write property="myNestedLevel.propertyTwo" />
<nested:write property="myNestedLevel.propertyThree" />
```

Can instead become...

```
<nested:nest property="myNestedLevel" >
  <nested:write property="propertyOne" />
  <nested:write property="propertyTwo" />
  <nested:write property="propertyThree" />
</nested:nest >
```

I create View Model objects for each of my Views. As some of these views maybe re used in other View JSP files, the View JSP nested in a View would have an equivalent ViewModel Object nested in another ViewModelObject which represents The Whole View with the nested (reused) View components.

Can anyone think of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, obvious approach is to use `<s:push>`:

```
<s:push value="myNestedLevel">
  ${propertyOne}
  ${propertyTwo}
  ${propertyThree}
</s:push>
```